# Fragment Reloading Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

There is an activity which is having a bottom toolbar having four tabs.
On each tap of the below tabs, a fragment is replaced with the container frame layout.
In all the fragments there is an API from which the data is loaded to the fragment. But the issue is how to avoid reloading of the data when once there is already loaded which affects the user experience.

```
public class HomeSellarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private LinearLayout llMessage, llMe, llHome, llAppointment;
private ImageView ivHome, ivMessage, ivAppointment, ivMe;
private TextView tvHome, tvMessage, tvAppointment, tvMe;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sellar_home);
    init();

    HomePageFragment homePage = new HomePageFragment();
    this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, homePage).commit();
    llMessage.setOnClickListener(this);
    llMe.setOnClickListener(this);
    llHome.setOnClickListener(this);
    llAppointment.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void init() {
    ivHome = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivHome);
    ivMessage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMessage);
    ivAppointment = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAppointment);
    ivMe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMe);
    llMessage = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llMessage);
    llMe = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llMe);
    llHome = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llHome);
    llAppointment = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llAppointment);
    tvHome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHome);
    tvAppointment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAppointment);
    tvMe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMe);
    tvMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == llMessage) {
        tvMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tvHome.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvAppointment.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvMe.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        ivHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_icon_blue);
        ivMessage.setImageResource(R.drawable.chat_icon_on_click);
        ivAppointment.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button_icon);
        ivMe.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_icon);
        MessagesFragment messages = new MessagesFragment();
        this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, messages).commit();
    }
    if (view == llMe) {
        tvMessage.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvHome.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvAppointment.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvMe.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        ivHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_icon_blue);
        ivMessage.setImageResource(R.drawable.chat_icon);
        ivAppointment.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button_icon);
        ivMe.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_icon_selected_copy);
        AccountHomeFragment accountHome = new AccountHomeFragment();
        this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, accountHome).commit();
    }
    if (view == llHome) {
        tvMessage.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvHome.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tvAppointment.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvMe.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));

        ivHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_icon);
        ivMessage.setImageResource(R.drawable.chat_icon);
        ivAppointment.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button_icon);
        ivMe.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_icon);
        HomePageFragment homePageFragment = new HomePageFragment();
        this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, homePageFragment).commit();
    }
    if (view == llAppointment) {
        tvMessage.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvHome.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvAppointment.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tvMe.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));

        ivHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_icon_blue);
        ivMessage.setImageResource(R.drawable.chat_icon);
        ivAppointment.setImageResource(R.drawable.music_icon);
        ivMe.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_icon);
        Services services = new Services();
        this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, services).commit();

    }
}
```

One of the fragment code:

```
public class HomePageFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private RecyclerView rvServices;
    private RecentServicesAdapter recentServicesAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private ImageView ivMailBox, ivProfileImage;
    private TextView tvStatus, tvMasterName, tvTitleName, tvTransactionYesterday, tvTransactionWeek, tvTransactionMonth, tvTransactionAmtYesterday, tvTransactionAmtWeek, tvTransactionAmtMonth;
    private SwitchButton switch_button;
    private Button btnIncomeRecord;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false);
        rvServices = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvServices);
        btnIncomeRecord = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnIncomeRecord);
        ivMailBox = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivMailBox);
        tvStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
        switch_button = (SwitchButton) view.findViewById(R.id.switch_button);
        tvMasterName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMasterName);
        tvTitleName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleName);
        tvTransactionMonth = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTransactionMonth);
        tvTransactionWeek = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTransactionWeek);
        tvTransactionYesterday = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTransactionYesterday);
        tvTransactionAmtMonth = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTransactionAmtMonth);
        tvTransactionAmtWeek = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTransactionAmtWeek);
        tvTransactionAmtYesterday = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTransactionAmtYesterday);
        ivProfileImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivProfileImage);
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        callApi();
        ivMailBox.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnIncomeRecord.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;

    }

    private void callApi() {
        progressBar.show();
        progressBar.setMessage("Getting HomePage Data");
        progressBar.setCancelable(false);
        if (NetworkHelper.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
            ApiSellarConnection.getHomePageData(AppSharedPref.getCustomerId(getActivity()), AppSharedPref.getStoreId(getActivity())).enqueue(new Callback<HomePageResponse>() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<HomePageResponse> call, Response<HomePageResponse> response) {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        if (response.body().getSellerData().getActiveSellerStatus() == 0) {
                            tvStatus.setText("Offline");
                            switch_button.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        if (response.body().getSellerData().getActiveSellerStatus() == 1) {
                            tvStatus.setText("Online");
                            switch_button.setChecked(true);
                        }
                        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(response.body().getSellerData().getSellerLogo()).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.pro)).into(ivProfileImage);
                        tvMasterName.setText(response.body().getSellerData().getUserName());
                        tvTitleName.setText(response.body().getSellerData().getTitle());

                        tvTransactionMonth.setText("" + response.body().getMonthlyStatitics().getNoOfTransactions());
                        tvTransactionAmtMonth.setText(response.body().getMonthlyStatitics().getTotalSale());

                        tvTransactionWeek.setText("" + response.body().getWeeklyStatitics().getNoOfTransactions());
                        tvTransactionAmtWeek.setText(response.body().getWeeklyStatitics().getTotalSale());

                        tvTransactionYesterday.setText("" + response.body().getYesterdayStatitics().getNoOfTransactions());
                        tvTransactionAmtYesterday.setText(response.body().getYesterdayStatitics().getTotalSale());

                        recentServicesAdapter = new RecentServicesAdapter(response.body().getRecentOrderList(), getActivity());
                        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        rvServices.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                        rvServices.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                        rvServices.setAdapter(recentServicesAdapter);
                        rvServices.setFocusable(false);
                        rvServices.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Response Code " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    progressBar.cancel();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<HomePageResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    progressBar.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            progressBar.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Poor Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == ivMailBox) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MailBoxActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (view == btnIncomeRecord) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyIncomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("transactYesterday", tvTransactionYesterday.getText());
            intent.putExtra("transactWeek", tvTransactionWeek.getText());
            intent.putExtra("transactMonth", tvTransactionMonth.getText());
            intent.putExtra("transactAmtYesterday", tvTransactionAmtYesterday.getText());
            intent.putExtra("transactAmtWeek", tvTransactionAmtWeek.getText());
            intent.putExtra("transactAmtMonth", tvTransactionAmtMonth.getText());
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post some code because it's unclear which elements you are using. Usually you can set the `offscreenPageLimit` like in a `ViewPager` and prevent the *lazy loading* you are describing... You can also use the same instance of the `Fragment` rather then creating a new one on every tab click.

Comment: @HedShafran no i m not using view pager there is custom bottom bar on each tap there is a fragment loaded. How to avoid reloading of data in such a case.

Comment: Make sure you create each `Fragment` instance only once, and reuse existing instances.. But without seeing the code, I can't tell you what to change...

Comment: can this issue be managed by following the life cycle of the fragment?You can review the activity code

Comment: You can fetch your data using a separate object (Like a manager class which is a single instance). This way you're data is not related to the life cycle of the Fragments. And then each fragment can request the relevant data when needed (and/or listen to a callback when the data is ready/refreshed).. For example ==> `MyManager.getInstance().getData()`

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options such as accessing data over your singleton object, using new architecture components library's ViewModel. But If I were you I would use ViewModel with live data option

If you want to use singleton solution, you can access data like

```
 DataProvider.getInstance().loadHomeData(new RequestListener<Home>(){
   void onDataLoad(Home home){
   //...
 }
})
```

If you want to user ViewModel you can find an example at Google's official[page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below updated Code: It is working

```
public class HomeSellarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private LinearLayout llMessage, llMe, llHome, llAppointment;
private ImageView ivHome, ivMessage, ivAppointment, ivMe;
private TextView tvHome, tvMessage, tvAppointment, tvMe;
private AccountHomeFragment accountHomeFragment = new AccountHomeFragment();
private MessagesFragment messagesFragment = new MessagesFragment();
private Services ser = new Services();
private HomePageFragment homePageFragment = new HomePageFragment();
private Fragment active = accountHomeFragment;
private final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sellar_home);
    init();

    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, accountHomeFragment, "4").hide(accountHomeFragment).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, ser, "3").hide(ser).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, messagesFragment, "2").hide(messagesFragment).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, homePageFragment, "1").commit();

    active = homePageFragment;
    llMessage.setOnClickListener(this);
    llMe.setOnClickListener(this);
    llHome.setOnClickListener(this);
    llAppointment.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void init() {
    ivHome = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivHome);
    ivMessage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMessage);
    ivAppointment = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAppointment);
    ivMe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMe);
    llMessage = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llMessage);
    llMe = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llMe);
    llHome = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llHome);
    llAppointment = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llAppointment);
    tvHome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHome);
    tvAppointment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAppointment);
    tvMe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMe);
    tvMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == llMessage) {
        tvMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tvHome.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvAppointment.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvMe.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        ivHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_icon_blue);
        ivMessage.setImageResource(R.drawable.chat_icon_on_click);
        ivAppointment.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button_icon);
        ivMe.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_icon);

        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(messagesFragment).commit();
        active = messagesFragment;


    }
    if (view == llMe) {
        tvMessage.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvHome.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvAppointment.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvMe.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        ivHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_icon_blue);
        ivMessage.setImageResource(R.drawable.chat_icon);
        ivAppointment.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button_icon);
        ivMe.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_icon_selected_copy);

        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(accountHomeFragment).commit();
        active = accountHomeFragment;

    }
    if (view == llHome) {
        tvMessage.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvHome.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tvAppointment.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvMe.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));

        ivHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_icon);
        ivMessage.setImageResource(R.drawable.chat_icon);
        ivAppointment.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button_icon);
        ivMe.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_icon);

        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(homePageFragment).commit();
        active = homePageFragment;


    }
    if (view == llAppointment) {
        tvMessage.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvHome.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        tvAppointment.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tvMe.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
        ivHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_icon_blue);
        ivMessage.setImageResource(R.drawable.chat_icon);
        ivAppointment.setImageResource(R.drawable.music_icon);
        ivMe.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_icon);
        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(ser).commit();
        active = ser;

    }
}
```

}